# on click of path in d3 enlarge it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to enlarge a path when i click on it (animating it to the size as well)

(the is no id for the element I am clicking on as these are generated dynamically)

I am trying to do this in the on click event of the object

the path is of a d3.svg.symbol by the way

I have used the following but it is not enlarging, any ideas please?

```
//this runs through but seems to do nothing
var tmp = d3.select(this);
tmp.transition()
.duration(500)
.size(500);

//this error on .transition() line saying the function is undefined 
var tmp = d;
tmp.transition()
.duration(500)
.size(500);
```

i have been looking at this issue for a bit now and just cannot work it out.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: You need to set an attribute that will make it larger, e.g. `d3.select(this).transition().style("stroke-width", 5)`.

Comment: ah thanks alot Lars that went through a treat, ill have a play to get my desired effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What lars Kotthoff recommended corrected the issue

> You need to set an attribute that will make it larger, e.g.
>   d3.select(this).transition().style("stroke-width", 5).